# What's the difference between consuming a named pipe file with cat and with read, and why the latter fails with 'Interrupted system call'?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, named-pipes, io-redirection

I'm writing async tasks in a shell script and I am coordinating them with a pipe channel for showing on screen what's happening (and more).

Something like this:

```
long_task1 | very_long_task2 | other_long_task3 &

reporter_task
```

`long_task1`, `very_long_task2` and `other_long_task3` are writing their status and progresses in a named pipe called `channel.pipe`. `reporter_task` is consuming `channel.pipe` showing on screen some information for the user.

If I implement `reporter_task` like this

```
cat 'channel.pipe' | while IFS= read -r msg; do
    # code
done
```

everything works fine, but if I implement it in this way

```
while IFS= read -r msg; do
    # code
done < channel.pipe
```

it fails with an `Interrupted system call` error message.

Why using the latter syntax causes the pipe to be interrupted?

Comment: I think your operating system and `bash` version will be relevant. This sound bug-like to me.